# Difference between System.getProperty("COMPUTERNAME") and InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

Tags: java, windows, jboss

I need to log the machine name within my server module which is running in JBoss server. I found two approaches to get the machine name.
I need to know the difference between following two approaches.

```
System.getProperty("COMPUTERNAME")
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Comment: Don't know for the second one, but the first one may be abused by script or command line e.g  `set COMPUTERNAME=WHATEVERNAME` .